# How to bundle sortablejs in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, sortablejs, weboptimizer

I am writing a Typescript file that has this import statement:

```
import Sortable from "sortablejs";
```

I then encountered the following error when I run the web app:

```
Failed to resolve module specifier "sortablejs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

To solve it, in my Razor page, I included the following code:

```
<script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "sortablejs": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/sortablejs@1.15.0"
      }
    }
</script>
```

It works fine but I read that `importmap` is not supported by Safari. Thus, I am looking for an alternative solution.

Presently I am using `WebOptimizer` to bundle my files and I would like to continue using that instead of `Webpack` or others.